# Firebird: Query execution time in iSQL

Tags: firebird, execution-time

I would like to get query execution time in `iSQL`.

For instance :

```
SELECT * FROM students;
```

How do i get query execution time ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`SET STATS`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-set-stats):

```
SQL> SET STATS;
SQL> SELECT * FROM RDB$DATABASE;
... query output removed ....

Current memory = 34490656
Delta memory = 105360
Max memory = 34612544
Elapsed time= 0.59 sec
Buffers = 2048
Reads = 17
Writes 0
Fetches = 270
SQL>
```